# How to Connect two or more Databases in Visual Basic?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I need to programm something in VB that connects two or more mdb databases but I don't know how I am supposed to do that. I guess that I have to load all Databases to connect table by table. And save it again as ".mdb" (I don't know the commands for that - I think I can find them, but it would be nice if you could post them here).
I googled but I can't find the right answer - like I am using the wrong words for my problem...

It would be very nice if you could help me :)

Database example:
DB1:
-DB1_Table1
-DB1_Table2
-DB1_Table3

DB2:
-DB2_Table1
-DB2_Table2
-DB2_Table3

ConnectedDB(DB1 = master / DB2 = slave):
-DB1_Table1 + DB2_Table1
-DB1_Table2
-DB1_Table3 + DB2_Table3

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Assuming you are using `DAO` you can have more than one `Database` object in your code (I suppose you could do the same with `ADO`)

Comment: Separate the DBs as different layers(separate classes for each), each one connects to their DB, calling code asks for data from the DB class it chooses. Connecting to a DB is done by a connection string and some form of DB objects i.e. Entity Framework, ADO, etc...

Comment: Well for what do I have to search if I want to do what I wrote above? I already used a OLEDB connection to show what's in the databases, but I don't know how to connect them. I've read "joining", " connecting", "insert" and "update" but I can't find out whats correct for my problem...

Comment: [DAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx)

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`? Is MySQL actually involved?

Comment: @GordThompson, good question, but they did say more than one DB - so maybe more than one type? Rasalas, can you answer that?

Comment: No, it's just .mdb. I learned a bit Java and I saw that the Database Command lines are very similar - that's why I added MySQL. Maybe I was wrong there...

Answer (score 2):

In "C:\Users\Public\test\DB1.mdb" I have [DB1_Table1] containing

```
ID  DB1_Text
--  --------------
 1  value from DB1
```

In "C:\Users\Public\test\DB2.mdb" I have [DB2_Table1] containing

```
ID  DB2_Text
--  --------------
 1  value from DB2
```

In VB.NET the following code ...

```vb
Using con As New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
            "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\test\DB1.mdb;"
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText =
                "SELECT " &
                    "DB1_Table1.DB1_Text, " &
                    "DB2_Table1.DB2_Text " &
                "FROM " &
                    "DB1_Table1 " &
                    "INNER JOIN " &
                    "[;Database=C:\Users\Public\test\DB2.mdb].DB2_Table1 " &
                        "ON DB1_Table1.ID = DB2_Table1.ID"
        Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rdr.Read
            Console.WriteLine(rdr("DB1_Text") & " | " & rdr("DB2_Text"))
        Loop
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Using
```

... produces

```
value from DB1 | value from DB2
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll try that <3 seems to be "inner join" what I was searching for...