# VB6 - Inserting a data to an Access Table from a mySQL Table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vb6

I have a desktop application created via VB6 using Access Database and MySQL

The application is deployed in client computers without MS Access.

The MS Access Database and MySQL Database have the same tables.

What I want to do is copy the table data from MySQL Database into the Access Table using the VB6 Application.  I was thinking of using something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Target (ID, Value)
SELECT ID, Value
FROM Source WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Target WHERE Target.ID = Source.ID)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That's the problem.  I don't know where to run the query since its from two different data sources.  Can I just go like dbAccess.Excecute "INSERT INTO tblTest.dbAccess (ID, Values) SELECT ID, Value FROM tblTest.dbmySQL WHERE NOT EXISTS...

Comment: Example with 2 mdb db. See if you can adapt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047864/how-to-connect-two-or-more-databases-in-visual-basic

Comment: If ID and Value are unique index, the `WHERE` clause should not be needed.

Comment: @June7 : Tried adapting the code from your link but no luck.  I can't seem to call the MySQL database.  As for your 2nd comment, I need the `WHERE` clause since this checks if the ID exists in the Access Database already.

Comment: If the ID is a unique index or primary key, Access won't allow duplicate record - it will just fail to commit to table. But using it shouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can directly query ODBC data sources from Access:

```
INSERT INTO Target (ID, Value)
SELECT ID, Value
FROM [ODBC;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};Server=myServer;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;].Source 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Target WHERE Target.ID = Source.ID)
```

You need to execute this query on the Access database (I recommend doing it using DAO), and then that will connect and load the data from MySQL.

Comment: While there were a few nuances and things to change in terms of the DAO version and the last SELECT query, (like setting it to one column instead of an asterisk) this answer works for me.  Thank you!